Clarification of multicollinearity when not performing a regression analysis
I need some clarification on the subject of multicollinearity.
In my study, I’m analyzing several environmental parameters (such as soil chemistry metrics) across three soil types (see the table below for reference). I’ve created boxplots for each parameter in these soil types, performed a PCA to assess potential clustering, and examined correlations between these environmental parameters and the most abundant species identified in the soils.
EDIT to further explain the context:In this project, my primary aim is to assess whether the type of soil affects the measured parameters. To address this, I started with simple boxplots combined with Kruskal-Wallis and Wilcoxon tests for each parameter across the different soil types. While I have focused on soil chemistry for simplicity in the discussion, I also have data from leaf ionomics and multispectral imaging. To make the analysis more manageable, I need to reduce the number of variables. Therefore, I am verifying multicollinearity to identify and exclude highly correlated variables. I was under the impression that it is standard practice to select only one representative variable from a group of highly correlated ones, regardless of the type of analysis being performed.
Regarding the soil species section, I have also conducted metabarcoding analyses of the soil microbiome. This has provided tables containing the abundances of Amplicon Sequence Variants (ASVs) in the samples. I aim to determine if there is a relationship between the measured environmental parameters and the soil microbiome composition. To explore this, I performed an NMDS analysis on the microbiome data and used R’s envfit function to project vectors of the parameters onto the ordination plot, checking for associations with clustering patterns (see image). I also have data for two additional treatments, but they are not directly relevant for now.
Once again, I am grouping the soil chemistry parameters to achieve two goals: (1) enhance the readability of the plots and (2) reduce redundancy among variables, as I believe it is common practice to exclude variables with high correlations from multivariate analyses.
Given this context, my question is: Is it indeed a common practice to remove variables due to multicollinearity, and if so, is it appropriate to do so in my specific analyses? 
My supervisor recommended evaluating multicollinearity among the environmental parameters. If multicollinearity is present, I would then select one representative variable from each correlated group to keep for further analysis, discarding the others. To address this, I initially performed Pearson correlation tests among the environmental variables, using
2>0.9
as a threshold to indicate multicollinearity. This led me to find high correlations among Dissolved Organic Carbon (DOC), Dissolved Nitrogen (DN), Organic Carbon (C%), Organic Nitrogen (N%), and conductivity. Based on this and the context of my study, I decided to retain DOC for my analysis.
However, as I’ve read further on this topic, I’m finding that multicollinearity is more complex and is commonly discussed in the context of regression analysis. For instance, the Variance Inflation Factor (VIF) is often mentioned as a tool for detecting multicollinearity, but it appears to apply specifically to regression contexts, which I am not using in this study.
My main question is: what would be an appropriate method for verifying multicollinearity in this case, ideally one supported by relevant literature?
Thank you for any guidance you can offer!



Soil
pH
Conductivity (uS/cm)
DOC (mg/g soil)
DN (mg/g soil)
N%
C%
C/N
ATP (nmol/g soil)




Manure
6.98
194.50
0.526
0.074
1.56
19.72
12.68
22.88


Manure
7.08
167.50
0.444
0.06
1.56
19.02
12.22
12.91


Manure
7.09
191.10
0.467
0.079
1.61
19.75
12.28
11.68


Manure
6.96
207.00
0.494
0.066
1.61
20.41
12.72
10.06


Manure
7.09
193.70
0.481
0.076
1.52
19.45
12.79
27.31


Manure
7.01
186.40
0.32
0.043
1.61
20.68
12.85
42.08


Manure
7.11
199.00
0.465
0.056
1.69
21.12
12.49
31.51


Manure
7.05
193.90
0.496
0.065
1.64
20.43
12.47
28.71


Manure
7.15
204.00
0.45
0.057
1.79
22.37
12.51
65.4


Manure
7.01
202.00
0.525
0.065
1.56
19.35
12.43
16.05


Manure
7.10
192.30
0.473
0.065
1.53
21.04
13.93
15.76


Manure
7.08
178.80
0.43
0.086
1.43
19.77
14.05
13.15


Sand
7.44
60.00
0.03
0.008
0.03
0.21
6.15
0.1


Manure
7.12
170.70
0.43
0.056
1.52
19.44
12.8
10.05


Peat
6.90
76.30
0.182
0.013
0.27
4.84
18.1
7.01


Sand
7.28
56.30
0.022
0.006
0.05
0.15
3.46
0.16


Sand
7.27
49.10
0.046
0.006
0.03
0.15
4.76
0.15


Sand
7.32
58.50
0.022
0.006
0.04
0.16
4.2
0.19


Sand
7.15
66.30
0.024
0.005
0.05
0.21
4.88
0.3


Sand
7.25
65.80
0.02
0.006
0.04
0.13
3.11
0.23


Sand
7.04
65.30
0.023
0.006
0.04
0.18
4.79
0.41


Sand
7.30
64.80
0.022
0.006
0.06
0.16
2.42
0.06


Sand
7.31
65.10
0.018
0.006
0.05
0.13
2.39
0.19


Sand
7.01
65.90
0.021
0.006
0.05
0.14
2.69
0.23


Peat
6.95
83.70
0.157
0.015
0.3
5.41
17.92
3.34


Peat
7.07
71.40
0.111
0.009
0.29
4.99
17.28
3.49


Peat
6.92
75.80
0.178
0.027
0.25
4.38
17.8
5.64


Peat
7.07
72.50
0.168
0.018
0.28
4.92
17.36
4.87


Peat
6.95
74.10
0.195
0.025
0.31
5.58
17.76
13.16


Peat
6.88
85.70
0.185
0.019
0.27
4.65
17.01
3.62


Peat
6.96
67.50
0.126
0.017
0.16
2.25
13.68
3.94


Peat
6.89
111.40
0.242
0.045
0.45
8.16
18.13
5.8


Peat
6.94
76.00
0.145
0.015
0.27
4.46
16.73
3.2


Peat
6.92
80.80
0.183
0.021
0.39
7.11
18.25
4.53


Peat
6.86
72.20
0.182
0.014
0.33
5.78
17.75
2.94


Peat
6.89
76.10
0.172
0.02
0.27
4.69
17.32
4.08




Welcome to Cross Validated! There is a formula for calculating the VIF that's used in linear regression, but using VIF to choose only 1 from among a larger number of variables might not be the best way to proceed. Please edit the question to say more about what you want to accomplish by analyzing "correlations between these environmental parameters and the most abundant species identified in the soils." That sounds like the species/abundance is the outcome variable, so there are ways to incorporate all your variables as predictors in the analysis without throwing away information.

@EdM Thanks for the response! I added further context

Any correct answer will emphasize that it's complicated, as you indicate.  One method to tease out groups of inter-related variables for this purpose is described in one chapter and illustrated in another chapter (out of five total) in Belsley, Kuh, & Welsh's book on Regression Diagnostics.

In general, there are better ways to "reduce the number of variables" than choosing 1 from a set of correlated measurement types. That puts a lot of weight on one particular type of measurement and throws away all of the others. There's not much to be gained by throwing away information.
Taking the top few principal components, which you have already examined, uses information from all the measurement types. That's the basis of principal component regression. See Section 6.3, "Dimension Reduction Methods," of An Introduction to Statistical Learning by James et al. for principal component regression, and Chapter 12 for other uses of principal components that might help with your work outside of the context of regression.
I took your data set into a data frame called soilData, renaming some of the columns. In this case, the first 3 principal components capture nearly 97% of the variance of the soil chemistry values. Using them would cut you down from 8 variables to 3.
pcSoil <- princomp(soilData[,2:9],cor=TRUE)
summary(pcSoil)
# Importance of components:
#                           Comp.1    Comp.2     Comp.3     Comp.4     Comp.5
# Standard deviation     2.3742842 1.2839036 0.66209899 0.44674257 0.22572001
# Proportion of Variance 0.7046532 0.2060511 0.05479688 0.02494737 0.00636869
# Cumulative Proportion  0.7046532 0.9107043 0.96550116 0.99044852 0.99681721
#                             Comp.6      Comp.7       Comp.8
# Standard deviation     0.127262902 0.090681713 0.0322998593
# Proportion of Variance 0.002024481 0.001027897 0.0001304101
# Cumulative Proportion  0.998841693 0.999869590 1.0000000000

Looking at the data directly often helps clarify how to proceed. In this particular case, the soil type seems to capture almost all of the information in the soil chemistry measurements.
library(tidyverse)
soilData %>% pivot_longer(cols=2:9, names_to="variable", values_to="value") %>%
ggplot(mapping=aes(x=Soil,y=value,color=Soil)) + 
facet_wrap(vars(variable),scales="free") + geom_jitter()


Except for ATP in manure and pH in sand, there isn't much variability of any measurement type within a soil type, and most measurement types show little or no overlap among soil types. So if you want to simplify your model with respect to these soil chemistry measurements, you might just use the soil type as the variable.
I suspect that you will find similar simplifications and ways to reduce the number of effective predictors with the other types of measurements you have made.
